# AngularJS debugging tools for IE like Batarang

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-extensions

I was wondering if there are any alternative plugins to the Chrome extension Batarang as far as debugging and profiling for Internet Explorer (it can even be Edge, that would be fine).

Our organization has recently banned Chrome and we do heavy AngularJS development, so it would be nice to have a good tool for troubleshooting weird issues

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no comparable tool for IE but the extension are comming for EDGE : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/#available-extensions, so wait and see....